# How do I check for the presence of numbers at a specific point in a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create Javascript code that takes 3 separate numerical inputs from a string. The string is generated by a user sending a message to a Discord bot and is designed to eventually roll three different types of dice (Attribute dice, bonus dice, and gear dice).

The syntax for the message is:

```
!m 5a 10b 3g
```

It is possible for the dice pools for the attribute dice (5a) in this example and the bonus dice (10b) in this example to go up to double (never triple) digits, but *not* gear dice. What I'm trying to do is detect the three numerical inputs in this syntax, which can be either 11, 12, or 13 characters in length depending on how long the dice pools are.

Here's what I've got at the moment..

```
            // If one of the stats is double-digits.

            if (length === 12) {
              var attribDice = parseInt(message.substring(3, 4));
              console.log(attribDice);
              var bonusDice = parseInt(message.substring(6, 8));
              console.log(bonusDice);
              var gearDice = parseInt(message.substring(10, 11));
              console.log(gearDice);
            }

            // If two of the stats are double-digits.

            if (length === 13) {
              var attribDice = parseInt(message.substring(3, 5));
              console.log(attribDice);
              var bonusDice = parseInt(message.substring(7, 9));
              console.log(bonusDice);
              var gearDice = parseInt(message.substring(11, 12));
              console.log(gearDice);
            }

            // If all of the stats are single digits.
            if (length === 11) {
              var attribDice = parseInt(message.substring(3, 4));
              console.log(attribDice);
              var bonusDice = parseInt(message.substring(6, 7));
              console.log(bonusDice);
              var gearDice = parseInt(message.substring(9, 10));
              console.log(gearDice);
            }
```

The problem with this code at the moment is the 12 character length string: I need the code to detect whether the attribDice or the bonusDice are two-digit numbers, and parse them accordingly. I'm still very much a beginner to JavaScript, so I'd really appreciate some help! I'm sure there's probably a far more efficient way of doing this, too. Please let me know!

Comment: Could you just [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string based on spaces?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that's a much better way of doing it that I didn't know of!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with breaking down the input in to separate parts by [splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string in to 4 parts

```
var parts = input.split(' ');
```

Now you have in parts[0] your command "!m", in parts[1] "5a", in parts[2] "10b", etc.

You can still use parseInt() to get the numerical value for each dice as it will ignore trailing chars. Consider using the second parameter of [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) just to make sure the result is as expected.

I would recommend you validate the the result of parseInt and make sure it falls in to the range you expect them to be as you are parsing user provided data.
A user might send you "!m 9999999a 99999999b 9999999g" and if you do a lot of work depending on those numbers they might be able to break your app.